# jQuery val() not working on option appended through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery/Ajax function that is appending 2 `<option>`s to a `<select>`.

```
function addOption() {  
    var author = $("#authors").val();
    $('#books').empty(); 
    $('#books').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>'); 
$.ajax({ 
      type: "post", 
      url:  "books.php", 
      data: { author:author }, 
      success: function(response){ 
          $('#books').append(response); 
      } 
    }); 
}
```

`response` comes back as -

```
<option value="bookA">Book A</option>
<option value="bookB">Book B</option>
```

and now `books` is -

```
<select id="books">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="bookA">Book A</option>
<option value="bookB">Book B</option>
</select>
```

This works great.

Now I want to set the `selected` `option` using `.val()` after calling `addOption()` -

```
$('#authors').change( function(){
addOption();
$('#books').val('bookB');
});
```

This does not make `Book B` selected.

If I hard code the `.append()` it works -

```
function addOption() {  
    var author = $("#author").val();
    $('#books').empty(); 
    $('#books').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>');
    $('#books').append('<option value="bookA">Book A</option>\n<option value="bookB">Book B</option>);
}

$('#authors').change( function(){
addOption();
$('#books').val('bookB');
});
```

Is there a reason why my option(s) appended in the `.ajax` function cannot be selected using `.val()`, put it can if I append them directly?

Comment: You need to use an on() handler as the content is added dynamically.

Comment: @jtheman: I don't think that's necessary since `#authors` isn't removed/added.

Comment: @pimvdb Correct, my mistake. Callback is the way to go!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the AJAX call is asynchronous, so when you try to select the options, it hasn't been added to the select yet.

Use a callback in the function, so that you can do something when the response has arrived:

```
function addOption(callback) {  
  var author = $("#authors").val();
  $('#books').empty(); 
  $('#books').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>'); 
  $.ajax({ 
    type: "post", 
    url:  "books.php", 
    data: { author:author }, 
    success: function(response){ 
      $('#books').append(response); 
      callback();
    }
  }); 
}
```

Usage:

```
$('#authors').change( function(){
  addOption(function(){
    $('#dropdownB').val('bookB');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is asynchronous, when you set the value, there is no option with that value, you can put your code in your success callback.

```
  success: function(response){ 
      $('#books').append(response); 
      // ...
  }
```

Or set that value of `async` property of your Ajax request to `false`;

Comment: Although using `async` would give the desired behaviour, it should be mentioned that it also freezes the browser while it waits for the response, which might not be a desirable user experience.

Answer (score 2):

**A**JAX is **asynchronous**, meaning that when you call the addOption() method, it might (and probably will) return before the Ajax call has actually been made, so you are calling `$('#dropdownB').val('bookB');` before the Ajax callback has been triggered to append the options.

Try putting the `$('#dropdownB').val('bookB');` into the success callback of the ajax call and you should see it working.

Comment: Actually, the function will *always* return before the response is handled. Even if the response arrives immediately, it's won't be handled until you exit the outermost function (the change event handler) and return control to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is because ajax is *asynchronous*.  That is, by the time it returns and appends the new options to the select list, the browser engine has already continued and tried to set the value (which wasn't yet added).  Try moving the value setting logic to work as part of the ajax response.

Answer (score 1):

1) You should put `$('#dropdownB').val('bookB');` inside the success-event of your ajax-call, because AJAX is asynchronous and your request may not be done when you try to change the selected item, so there is no item to select yet.
2) You append to `#books` but change the selected item of `#dropdownB`. Those are two different ids and hence two different DOM elements.